# File.Open Access violation

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am opening a File in my windows service like this...

```
request.Report = File.Open(fName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite)
```

Object **Request** is a Third party DLL, which has a member **Report** of datatype "Stream", it reads the Content of File, but then keeps the file LOCKED, is there anyway I can push stream to "request.Report" & not have the file locked?

I tried...

```
Dim iStream As FileStream = File.Open(fName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite)
request.Report = iStream 
iStream.Close()
```

but got error "to Stream must implement the Write method."

Unfortunately I cant change the behavior of 3rd party DLL. **Report** Methods takes the File stream & then writes to it as well.

Thanks

Comment: A trivial solution would be to copy the file first.

Comment: please provide an example?

Comment: Is it possible to wait to call `iStream.Close` until after the `request` object is done writing to it?

Comment: Why would you want to break the lock at all if you know it's writing to the file?

Comment: I dont want to break the Lock, Service checks for new updates every hour, and once a file is been created by service it STAYS locked.

Comment: Steven Doggart SPOT on, you are absolutely correct:)..I am killing iStream after all tasks are finished by service...it seams like a different component was using the stream while I had it CLOSE before it. Thanks:)